# How to test for waiting threads within a lock

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, thread-safety

So I know you can use a semaphore and possibly other methods to determine if a lock will succeed and/or how many threads are waiting for the lock but can you do this from within the lock itself?

My situation is I have an event handler that could be called by many objects within a `List`. I want to do a test within a lock to see if all the objects are in the right state before proceeding. The objects transition to the appropriate state **and then** raise this event so in a single thread model when the last one raises this event, all objects will be in the right state and we proceed. But it occurred to me that, with multiple threads, multiple objects may be transitioned to the state I'm checking for but as yet have not processed this event as they are waiting at the lock. Therefore the conditional state check within the lock will be true but proceeding would be bad till all threads have finished processing this event. I need it to only be true as the last thread is processed to ensure we don't proceed too soon.

For example in semi realistic code:

```cs
object _LockObj = new object();

void Event_Handler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyObject originator = sender as MyObject;
    if(originator == null)
        return;

    *Do stuff with the originator*

    lock(_LockObj)
    {
        if(ListOfMyObjects.FindAll(o => o.State == DesiredState)
                          .Count == ListOfMyObjects.Count 
                                 && *nothing waiting at the lock*)
        {
            *Proceed*
        }
    }
}
```

I'm perfectly prepared to accept my approach is smelly to start with and that the solution I'm looking for is moot if I do it properly in the first place but I'm uncertain how to do it properly in a thread safe manner.

I was going to add yet more states to `MyObject` and manage the flow by setting the appropriate State in the `*Do stuff with the originator*` section but it didn't feel correct to be transitioning MyObject from here, not to mention I then have to implement a holding state for each state that raises an event which is getting smellier not simpler!

So if there is a simple way of doing the '*nothing waiting at the lock*' check then that's the way I'd like to go unless I'm missing a really simple to implement pattern that helps in this scenario.

Comment: You are asking for a threading race bug as a feature.  A nanosecond after you concluded that no thread is waiting, a thread can enter the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, unfortunately, testing for other threads waiting on the lock() statement will not get you what you want. For example, if objects A, B and C have transitioned to the desired state and have raised their events, it's possible that the `Event_Handler` is only called for one object, say A at that point. The same handler will run for B and C at some point, later. So all your objects are now supposedly in the desired state, AND no threads are waiting at the lock, but you prob. don't want to "proceed". Even if you do, you need to consider, the same might happen an instant later for B and then again for C, so "proceed" may run three times...

It's a simple suggestion, but you can use a counter to test how many objects have actually raised the event. You could also use another list if a counter doesn't give sufficient information. The important part is that whichever method you use, only update the counter / list / other mechanism while inside a lock on the same `_LockObj`. Then probably reset that counter after *proceed* has run. If you need to access the counter somewhere else, make sure you use the same `lock(_LockObj)`, this will ensure you're not changing it while inside the other critical section.

```
object _LockObj = new object();
int _counter = 0;

void Event_Handler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyObject originator = sender as MyObject;
    if(originator == null)
        return;

    *Do stuff with the originator*

    lock(_LockObj)
    {
        ++_counter;
        if (_counter == ListOfMyObjects.Count)
        {
            *Proceed*

            _counter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Removed redundant check for objects' state.

Comment: Isn't the double check useless at this point? If the two parts of the if disaligns you won't ever be able to enter it.

Comment: Thanks @xanatos , have updated the code. It's possible that other parts of the code will update the objects' state and we still need to check it, but if that's the case, we should (A) see more code here and (b) should also assume _counter changes its value in the other sections too.

Comment: Ah how stupid of me not to consider the scenario where events enter the method after the check :( So whatever my solution is I need to track the completions independently and then only proceed once my independent test succeeds. Thanks for the sanity check :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about a simple synchronous work item queue? So when the event is raised it just queues up the processing, and the processing is done in order by a separate thread?

Comment: Not sure how that helps unless you can elaborate since I need to delay proceeding until it's appropriate and the question is how do I now when to proceed. I'm going to implement something based on Jonno's response above for now (since the deadline is pending) unless something simpler comes along.

Comment: In a single threaded model you say it works fine, presumably you have a mechanism for working out when an event is the last to be fired. If you use the same logic inside the work item so that it can determine if it should do the processing, you can treat it just like a single thread. In effect you're funnelling the events raised by multiple threads into a synchronous queue so that you can treat it like a single thread. I admit I may have rushed that answer, so I'm guessing that you actually want to have the processing bit asynchronous, but the rest not?